# celery chain is not triggering second task

Tags: python, celery, task

I have two celery Tasks which should be run in strict order.

```
def celery_run_tasks():
    chain(task_one.s(arg1, arg2), task_two.s(arg1, arg2)).apply_async()
```

So, first task taking `2 Arguments` and in the end Populating some data to PostgreSQL table.
After that second task should Start, get data from `FIRST table`, generate new calculations and post them to `SECOND` PostgreSQL table.

The problem what I see with my code that its populating all data to first table, but second one is empty. I tried different variations with Chord and Groups and its still does not work.

Let me know what you think and Please be specific. Thank you.

P.S. I did check Celery documentation!, please don't just post link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So issue was that first task was sending result of it to second task as first argument. So my second task receive 3 arguments instead of two and give error.
To avoid it make second task as `si` which mean not accept any arguments from previous tasks and it will work:

```
def celery_run_tasks():
    chain(task_one(arg1, arg2), task_two.si(arg1, arg2)).apply_async()
```